# The automorphism groups of smallest grammars of a language string are isomorphic

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions, formal-languages, automata-theory

Let $s \in \Sigma^*$ be a formal language string.  Consider the automorphism group of $s$, defined to be the set of all permutations of positions of $s$ that leave $s$ fixed.  For instance $G(abab) = \{\text{id}, \ (1,3), \ (2,4), \ (1,3)(2,4)\}$.

What about automorphisms of the associated grammars of strings.  For instance:

$$ g = \\
A \to BB \\
B \to ab
$$

has automorphism group $\langle (1,2) \rangle$ (you simply re-index the symbols however you want and compute the group that fixes a *set* of strings which are the rule RHS's of the grammar).

Have you heard of this conjecture or a reformulation of it?:

*The automorphism groups of the smallest grammars of a string are isomorphic to one another.*

### An example

$$
s = abc \ abc \ abc \ ab
$$.

Positions are $1, 2, \dots, |s|$.  The symmetry group of the string acts on this position set as a subset of $S_{|s|}$.  Find the symmetry group as $G(s) = \langle \text{id}, (1,4), (2,5), (3,6), (1,7),(2,8),(3,9),(1,10), (2,11) \rangle$.  Now let's choose a grammar of $s$ that's strictly smaller than $|s|$.  How about

$$g = \\
A \to BB abc ab \\
B \to abc
$$

Then order the positions accordingly to the order: BB abc ab, abc.  Then the symmetry group is $G(g) = \langle (1,2), (3,6), (3,8),(4, 7),(4,9),(5,10)\rangle$.

Comment: (1) Do you mean: Whenever we have two smallest grammars computing the same string, their automorphism groups are  isomorphic?  (2) On which set does the  automorphism group of a grammar act if the RHSs have different lengths? (3) What do you mean by "smallest"? The smallest number of rules, the smallest number of nonterminals, the smallest number of symbols, including or not including arrows and/or commas, etc?

Comment: (4) If I apply the permutation to the right hand sides of your grammar, I get $A\to BB$, $B\to ba$, which generates a different string.

Comment: @Goldstem  the set acted on are the positions on the RHS of the grammars.  You can list the grammar RHS's in any order, label their positions and compute the symmetry group.  So $\langle 1,2 \rangle$ applied to the grammar as listed: $BB$, then $ab$, we have a fixed grammar by the symmetry of $BB$.  The smallest grammar has the standard definition of the total number of symbols on RHS's of grammar rules.  SO, in order to do this, each grammar you act on you fix an order of positions within the grammar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the grammars $A \to aaaaa$ and $A \to BaB$, $B \to aa$ are both minimal (5 symbols).

If I understand your definitions correctly, the automorphism group of the first one is $S_5$ with $120$ elements, the automorphism group of the second is $S_2\times S_3$ with $12$ elements.